# WSUS won't apply SQL Server update

Tags: sql-server, wsus

I have a SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1 machine and I want to apply KB2716440 to it from Microsoft bulletin MS12-070 using WSUS. I have placed two nodes in a cluster into a group called `Dev`. I have approved KB2716440 to the Dev group and it has a status of `Install` with no deadline.

On the target machines I have checked for updates using Windows Update and it says there are none available. If I look at the status report for the KB on the WSUS machine, the target hosts appear in the report with `Approval` as `Install` and `Status` as `Not Applicable`. The registry keys on the targets look like this:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate]
"WUServer"="http://wsus.server.name"
"WUStatusServer"="http://wsus.server.name"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU]
"AUOptions"=dword:00000003
"NoAutoUpdate"=dword:00000000
"ScheduledInstallDay"=dword:00000000
"ScheduledInstallTime"=dword:00000003
"UseWUServer"=dword:00000001
"NoAUShutdownOption"=dword:00000001
```

Any ideas why the update is not being applied?

Comment: I also ran `wuauclt /detectnow /reportnow` on the target host, and then ran Windows Update to check for updates, but the host thinks there are no updates available.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment but check following:

- do target machine need that update (so is that update listed as needed for target machine)
- is update already downloaded ? (normally wsus is downloading updates after approval)

  check %systemroot%\WindowsUpdate.log for eventual errors / details